# Help in correcting or bypassing a bug resulting shifted screen in my ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, monitor

On Ubuntu 15.10 using an nVidia gtx 960 card, and life was great until nVidia released driver 355.

Everything was fine with the 352 series and when I updated to 355 I got the [shifted screen bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8ZuX.jpg).

As you can see the screen is shifted to the right and I can't correct this using the monitor auto-adjust or the monitor manual correction (I can re-shift the image a little to the left but not enough to fix this).

I contacted nVidia and they claim they can't test my error because they don't have my monitor brand.

*Is there a way I can override the x server position through Ubuntu to correct the issue?*

Things I've done already: tried another distro, tried another kernel, tried another desktop manager (cinammon, mate, unity, ubuntu classic), changed VGA cable, tried a HDMI - VGA converter, changed DVI-VGA adapter, even bought a new GPU (this started happening with a 750ti, I now got a 960).

**Edit** - this monitor has a VGA connector only, so I have to use the dvi - vga plug that comes with the gpu. If I revert to driver 352 the bug goes away; the monitor is an Asus VW222S LCD monitor

[Here are paste logs](http://pastebin.com/SZijwWHA) from xorg with the 361 driver (shifted screen bug)

Comment: Can you open a terminal and enter `xrandr -s 0` to see what happens? Have you tried a different refresh rate? Doesn't Nvidia provide a tool for correcting the screen position?

Comment: well, your command turned my screen at a lower resolution and still with the screen shifted to the right, Nvidia either provides no tool or i simply am ignorant of such tool, the nvidia guy i mailed from support specified no tool.

Comment: This is interesting, i cycled xrandr -s 1 2 3 4 and noticed it refered to the resolution modes nvidia has in its gui app, and besides 1680x1050 , all resolutions with "scaled" replicate the bug. as well, other lower resolutions dont.

Answer (score 0):

This is Ubuntu, this is not Windows: newer is not always better: I'm running on `nvidia-352` and am very happy with everything.

If the 352 series works flawlessly, *keep using that one and skip 355*.  If some day 365 comes out, try that one and if it gives you better performance, also use it but if you get worse performance/features/... *just roll back!*

(Oh and I'm on 14.04 LTS too, because I *like* stable and working applications, kernels and drivers...)

### ;-)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Good Luck running vulkan games on 352; the vulkan driver has the same bug

Comment: Too bad you're a low-rep user, or I would try to help you more, but you don't have enough reputation to chat, so go earn 20 rep and then leave me another note here: that's enough to talk in chat.

Comment: I get credits by helping out?  Nice system

Comment: Yes: if you're a native English speaker or have a very good level of English: it's actually easy: edit some other posts that contain errors and you'll have 20 after 10 edits, or give 2 good answers to other people's problems...  **;-)**  I'll get an nVidia expert involved with your question...

Comment: Sure let me get the time between the baby the wife and my work ill squeeze what i can to help out;

Comment: The expert came back to me and told me you should:  drop to a terminal, remove all nvidia drivers, reboot in nomodeset and clean up even further, reboot and install 361 again...

Comment: tell the expert i went as far to run a pendrive installer, ran the "try me" installed the 361 from there and i get the shifted screen in the pendrive session, purging the drivers and rebooting and reinstalling didnt sort the matter either. (i had nomodeset in grub already)

Comment: Sorry, no solution then...  Do you want me to delete my answer???

Comment: No way; your answer was quite pertinent i have requested assistance from nvidia and ended up with a sorry your monitor model has a issue and we cant replicate ; and when i created a thread in their forums so people with the bug could post their monitor model so nvidia could have a chance to replicate the bug i was shadow banned and my threads became invisible and support stoped replying to my tickets.

Comment: Wow!  And they get paid to actually solve problems!  :O  Final tip: go back to 352, and patiently wait for the next release...  It's bound to be solved some time!  **;-)**

Comment: Well this Journey was very productive i learned tons of tricks regarding xrandr and vídeo drivers i learned how to acess logs and how to read them; i joined this community and had fun in helping around (i intend on keeping doing that)  so it was actually cooler.  As for my solution -  i ordered a hdmi monitor from Amazon to replace this one and pray the guy that buys my old monitor in Ebay doesnt use ubuntu and nvidia :p

Comment: @CarlosSarria: **:D :D :D**